# Will Nvidia Geforce GT 1030 work?

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have a GT 1030 so I am wondering will it work with Blender CUDA? If yes, what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Nvidia GeForce GT 1030 supports CUDA 6.1 rendering, therefore it is compatible with the most recent version of Blender Cycles rendering. (Currently 2.92). To make it work, simply select and enable it as a Cycles CUDA rendering device in the Blender Preferences, then select GPU rendering in the Cycles rendering properties panel.